# Making submit button, change color when all inputs are filled

Tags: jquery, form-submit, forms

im currently thinking about how it would be possible to change the color of the input submit button, when all of the inputs have been filled out, would anyone know that by any chance?

I guess you can use php for that?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this, but it is kind of buggy, it does not really update before i press backspace a couple of times.:

```
    $(function() {
     $('form input[type=text], form input[type=email]').keydown(function() {
        var empty = false;

        // kører igennem alle inputs, og tjekker om de indeholder noget
        $('form input[type=text], form input[type=email]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') { // hvis feltet er tomt
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (!$('form input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
            empty = true;
        }

        if (empty == false) {
            // hvis alle felter er udfyldt
            $('form input[type=submit]').css('background-color', 'blue');
        } else {
            // hvis ikke alle felter er udfyldt
            $('form input[type=submit]').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
     });
    });
```

Comment: @halfer Would you by any chance know this?

Comment: Javascript, actually... Do you have just text fields in the form?

Comment: @nevermind No i do not, all text inputs and one email

Comment: There's no need for PHP, you can do this in JS. Just check all input items after one of them has changed and decide whether all of them have been filled or not

Comment: I don't really know how to use jquary.

Comment: @Athax You don't have to use jQuery if you don't want to. It can be done in pure javascript

Comment: @balping comforting, I don't know javascript either.

Comment: @Athax OK, I've done it for you, check my answer. If you don't understand something, just ask. But if you are working with HTML, you'd better start learning JS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a requirements specification rather than any attempt to solve the problem or a question...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, not PHP. PHP is server-side only, meaning that all the PHP has already run when you see a webpage.

Look at jquery - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

Comment: I added some additional text.

Answer (score -1):

Check my little example

```
<html>
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check(){
            var tocheck = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "email"];
            var tf = document.getElementById("theform");
            var ok = true;
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<tocheck.length; i++){
                ok = ok && tf.elements[tocheck[i]].value != "";
            }
            document.getElementById("subm").style.color = ok ? "green" : "red";
        }
    </script>
</head>


<body>

    <form id="theform">
        Text1: <input name="text1" type="text" onchange="check()" oninput="check()"></input><br/>
        Text2: <input name="text2" type="text" onchange="check()" oninput="check()" onchange="check()" oninput="check()"></input><br/>
        Text3: <input name="text3" type="text" onchange="check()" oninput="check()"></input><br>
        Email: <input name="email" type="email" onchange="check()" oninput="check()"></input><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="subm" value="OK" style="color: red;"></input>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if i wanted to style both background-color: and color: ? can i keep the styling in the css file?

Comment: Yes, you can define classes in CSS, then you'll have to use `className` property: `document.getElementById("subm").className = ok ? "fine" : "error";`

Comment: And you can't decide whether a checkbox is "filled" or not. Maybe the user just doesn't want to have it checked and leaves it unchecked.

Comment: However if the checkbox must be checked for example if it's a checkbox for 'I have read and accept the terms bla bla' then you can add this line after the for cycle: `ok = ok && tf.elements["accept_terms"].checked;`

Comment: Would this make sence to you? @balping ? just added some additional text.

Comment: Yes, it would (if you are talking about the checkbox thing)

Answer (score -1):

One of my friends, found a great solution!

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            function check_inputs() {
                var empty = false;

                // kører igennem alle inputs, og tjekker om de indeholder noget
                $('form input[type=text], form input[type=email]').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') { // hvis feltet er tomt
                        empty = true;
                    }
                });

                if (!$('form input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
                    empty = true;
                }

                if (empty == false) {
                    // hvis alle felter er udfyldt
                    $('form input[type=submit]').css({
                                                    'background-color' : '#f4d24b',
                                                    'font-size' : '16px',
                                                    'font-weight' : '700',
                                                    'color' : '#272727',
                                                    });
                } else {
                    // hvis ikke alle felter er udfyldt
                    $('form input[type=submit]').css('background-color', '#1f1f1f');
                }
            }

            $('form input[type=text], form input[type=email]').keyup(function() {
                check_inputs();
            });

            $('form input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {   
                check_inputs();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Login</title> 
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
        <script src="jquery.min.js"</script> 
        <style> 
            .btn,.input-radius {border-radius:1px!important;} 
            p { font-weight: bold; padding-top: 47px; } #sub{ } 
        </style> 
        <script> 
            jQuery(document).ready(function (){ 
                jQuery("#sub").click(function(){ btncolor(); }); 
                    function btncolor(){ 
                    if (jQuery('#exampleInputPassword1').val().length > 0 || jQuery('#exampleInputEmail1').val().length > 0) { jQuery("#sub").css("background-color", "orange"); 
                    } 
                }
            }); 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <form> 
                <p>LOGIN</p> 
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-radius" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                </fieldset> 
                <fieldset class="form-group"> 
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-radius" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"> 
                </fieldset> 
                <button type="submit" id="sub" class="btn btn-primary grey-btn" onclick="return false;">Submit</button> 
                <small class="text-muted">Forgot password?</small>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```